# Mastic Odor In House After Skylight Replacement

Tags: roof, plaster, smell, skylight, mastic

We had a new roof put on our home last week.  They replaced our old cracked skylight with a new one.

The old skylight was installed in an odd way, and they had to shave some drywall down that was built up around the old one when they put the new one on (even though it’s nearly the same size).  The result is that there’s now a bit of a rim or “lip” just inside the skylight frame.  There’s some roofing material on the lip - underlayment paper and some mastic.  The mastic smell occasionally flares up inside the house, which weirds me out.  Doesn’t seem like the best thing to be inhaling - though I assume the smell will continue to lessen (it’s only been a few days).  Is that a valid thing to be concerned about?

The roofer doesn’t finish skylight interiors, so I’m trying to figure out what to do.  I was thinking someone could plaster over the lip with the exposed roofing material?  That seems like that would help keep the smell at bay.  Thoughts?  Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]